# How to go backward to a certain position in Flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

For example, my lexer recognizes a function call pattern:

```
//i.e. hello(...), foo(...), bar(...)
FUNCALL     [a-zA-Z0-9]*[-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-_*][a-zA-Z0-9]*\(.\)
```

Now that flex recognizes the pattern, but it goes passed the last character in the pattern (i.e. after stored `foo(...)` inside `yytext`, the lexer will point to the next character after `foo(...)`)

How can I reset the lexer pointer back to the beginning of the function pattern? i.e. after recognizing `foo(..)`, I want to the lexer to point to the start of `foo(..)`, so I can start tokenizing it.

I need to do this because for each regex pattern, only one token can be returned for each pattern. i.e. after matching `foo(...)`, I can only return either `foo` or `(` or `)` with return statement but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Flex has a trailing context pattern match (manual excerpt below)  Read and understand the limitations before you use this.

> `r/s'
>
> ```
>  an `r' but only if it is followed by an `s'.  The text matched by
>  `s' is included when determining whether this rule is the longest
>  match, but is then returned to the input before the action is
>  executed.  So the action only sees the text matched by `r'.  This
>  type of pattern is called "trailing context".  (There are some
>  combinations of `r/s' that flex cannot match correctly. *Note
>  Limitations::, regarding dangerous trailing context.)
> ```

Presumably something like this:

```
FUNCALL     [a-zA-Z0-9]*[-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-_*][a-zA-Z0-9]*/\(.\)
```

You may find that it makes more sense to change your parser so you don't need to do this.